# How to export barcode from HTML to XLSX

Tags: datatable, export-to-excel, barcode

I am using datatable, and I have a barcode in it generated from a [JS library](https://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html). I am exporting data to XLSX, I can see all the data exporting fine except the barcode.

I tried exporting barcode using `=image([img_url], 3)` but it didn't worked too, although this formula only works on google sheets but in my case it's not working even on google sheets.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.!

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @moody no I didn’t.